# IPC in Message-Passing Systems - Direct Communication

Tags: operating-system, ipc, message-passing

According to the book 'operating systems concepts', it says:

> With direct communication, each process that wants to communicate must
>   explicitly name the recipient or sender of the communication. This
>   scheme exhibits symmetry in addressing. In this scheme, the send and
>   receive primitives are defined as:
>
> - Send(P, message): Send a message to process P
> - receive (Q, message)-Receive a message from process Q.
>
> In asymmetry only the sender names the recipient; the recipient is not
>   required to name the sender. In this scheme, the send and receive
>   primitives are defined as follows:
>
> - Send(P, message): Send a message to process P.
> - receive(id, message):Receive a message from any process; the variable id is set to the name of the process with which communication
>     has taken place.

I can't understand what is the difference? In asymmetric scheme, doesn't the `receive()` call need to specify the sender id?

Comment: For the asymmetric case, the book should've described it as `(senderID, message) = receive()` to make it clear that both `senderID` and `message` are outputs and not inputs (where it'd be `message = receive(senderID)` for the symmetric case).

Answer (score 0):

That the receive() call does not specify the sender id is the difference.   The implication is that the sender:receiver relationship is many to one (N:1), whereas the symmetric case is 1:1.  Many implementations offer secondary mechanisms to blur this implications.

In the N:1 case, there needs to be some explanation of the mechanisms for handling multiple simultaneous senders.   Explanations involve policy:first come first served; random; priority, capacity: #-threads, and perhaps inheritance of scheduling parameters and constraints.

In the 1:1 case, there is no need for policy or capacity, and it is safe to assume inheritance is innate.   Thusly, the 1:1 case is more amenable to automated analysis.

A 1:1 system that permits dynamic configuration of sender:receiver pairs can be even more complex than these identified systems.   In this sort of system, a sender may discover a receiver by some process which instantiates a receiver for this sender.  Uncovering the policy,capacity,inheritance attributes is more complex in this sort of arrangement.